# SSL Forge, Cloudflare and Digital Ocean

Tags: ssl, github, digital-ocean, cloudflare, forge

I am using Github + Laravel Forge + Cloudflare + Digital Ocean, and i have generated a signed certificate and:

1. In Forge panel inserted my private key and cert via Sites > your-site > SSL Certificates > Install Existing Certificate.
2. Activate the certificate
3. In CloudFlare panel, Crypto > SSL, choose “Full” (not strict)

But my site wiblog.dk says:
Your connection to this website is not completely secure

Why no Secure, with the green lock?

what have I forgotten here??

Comment: You don't say what browser(s) you are using; most now give green lock or bar only for an EV cert, which Cloudflare doesn't use unless you pay; see https://www.cloudflare.com/ssl/ at 'Custom Certificates'. However, (my) Chrome and Firefox ding you (black and yellow respectively) for **mixed content**: your page is fetching wiblog.dk/storage/settings/September2017/logo.png as HTTP -- which then 301's to HTTPS but could be intercepted and replaced before being redirected. IE11 doesn't ding you visibly but does give an error in console if enabled.

Comment: It works fine for me :) No errors, green bar.

Comment: Thanks for your time ti check, and coments !!

Answer (score 0):

Just did a quick check on your website using [this](https://www.sslchecker.com/sslchecker)

It says your website is missing **root2** certificate, can you re-check your certificate chain.

Comment: I have made the certificate on forge.com, but can not correct it, what do you recommend I can do?

// Henrik

Comment: A TLS server is not required to provide the root cert, see the RFCs (all the way back to 1999). And in any case that's the _Cloudflare_ cert's chain from a Cloudflare server, not the OP's and not changeable by the OP.

Comment: I removed the cert. and went back to http:
Then I'm generating a new cert. and directed .laravel .env to https: // and Wuptiiiiiii
Still, ROOT 2 Cert is missing?? .. but it works !!
I love it :-) .. Thanks for the help!